# Getting Keyerror while getting value of one dictionary by value from another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Code:

```
dict1 ={"a:b":"w","cd":"x","ef":"y","gh":"z"}
dict2 ={"a:b":"l","cd":"m","ef":"n","gh":"o"}

dict3 = {v:dict1[k] for k,v in dict2.iteritems()}
```

Expected output:

```
dict3 = {"l":"w","m":"x","n":"y","o":"z"}
print dict3
```

What I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "all.py", line 45, in <module>
dict3 = {v:dict1[k] for k,v in dict2.iteritems()}  
File "all.py", line 45, in <dictcomp>
dict3 = {v:dict1[k] for k,v in dict2.iteritems()}  
KeyError: 'a:b'
```

I want **dict3** to have `{k(value of dict2):v(values of dict1)}` // check expected output I have written above to better understand. How can I resolve this?

NOTE: "**a:b**" is the key, most of my keys have a `:` sign in keyname

Comment: It works for me ... `{'m': 'x', 'l': 'w', 'o': 'z', 'n': 'y'}` !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably do not have the exact same key in the second dict, though the total number of keys may be differernt. Also, the original code works for given sample data.

For now, you can remove the error by using a `.get` call instead of directly accessing the key:

```
dict1 ={"a:b":"w","cd":"x","ef":"y","gh":"z"}
dict2 ={"a:b":"l","cd":"m","ef":"n","gh":"o"}

dict3 = {v:dict1.get(k) for k,v in dict2.iteritems()}
```

If you print dict3, you should find some key with value `None` assigned to it (`None` is the default value of `.get` when key is not found).

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, this bypasses error, however output I get is faulty for my input data.

Sorry I forgot to mention my dict1 is nested dictionary that means an element can be of type (key:value   for example.  "color": "red") or (key:value where value is another dictionary for example  "fruit": {"color":"red", "shape": "round"} ) Does it makes any difference?

Or should I show you my input data and actual contents in my dict and dict2?

Comment: I tried to just replace the keys of dict1 with values of dict2 (where key of dect1 equal to key of dect2)      ` for k, v in dict2.iteritems():
        dict1[v] = dict1.pop(k) `

Comment: I tried to just replace the keys of dict1 with values of dict2 (where key of dect1 equal to key of dect2)     I used code                                             for k, v in dict2.iteritems():
        dict1[v] = dict1.pop(k)                IT GIVES KEY ERROR

Comment: @Ritzor I think you should close this question by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (since it solved your original question), and ask a new question with your nested dictionary and how to set the values. The format of Stack is anyway one question per post. It would also help, if in the new question you add the exact dictionaries (or a dict with dummy data but all keys to remove sensitive details) that you are using.